# Call cURL with modified offset values in a loop while more results are available

Tags: php, loops, curl, pagination

I am attempting to integrate a web service where the JSON response returns a URL for the next 1,000 results. What I have to do is loop the cURL to continue to process the request until the "next" variable is empty.

I am having an issue getting this done because I can not loop back up once I see the variable returned.

```
$url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/process/api/transactions/from/$yesterday/to/$today/for/company/21?offset=0&limit=1000"; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);                                                              
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");                                                                                                                                    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: $cookie"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);                                                                                                                                            

$result = curl_exec($ch);

file_put_contents(rj_array, $result, FILE_APPEND);

$server = file_get_contents(rj_array);

$json_result = json_decode($server, true);

$next = $json_result['next'];
```

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
while(!empty($next)){
    //Do the curl request again with the new URL $next
}
```

But I can not reset the `$next` variable each time.

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
$base_url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/process/api/transactions/from/$yesterday/to/$today/for/company/21?limit=1000";
$next = 0;
while( $next !== false ) {
    $url = $base_url . "&offset=" . $next;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);                                                              
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");                                                                                                                                    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: $cookie"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);                                                                                                                                            

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    file_put_contents(rj_array, $result, FILE_APPEND);

    $server = file_get_contents(rj_array);

    $json_result = json_decode($server, true);

    $next = $json_result['next'];
    if( /*test if next is empty*/ ) {
        $next = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do like the recursive function approach:

```
function crawler($url, $return) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: $cookie"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    file_put_contents(rj_array, $result, FILE_APPEND);

    $server = file_get_contents(rj_array);

    $json_result = json_decode($server, true);
    $return[$url] = $json_result; //set your return information in some array

    $next = $json_result['next'];

    if(!empty($next)) {
        return crawler($next, $return); //call again same function with next url and array of data that you would use later
    }

    return $return;
}

$url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/process/api/transactions/from/$yesterday/to/$today/for/company/21?offset=0&limit=1000";
$allJsonResults = crawler($url, []);
```

Comment: This is returning:

Comment: Array ( [https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/process/api/transactions/from/2016-11-17/to/2016-11-18/for/company/21?offset=0&limit=1000] => )

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend a pre-test loop or recursion, this is a task for a post-test loop.

Declare unchanging aspects of your curl call before entering the loop. Inside the loop manipulate the offset and limit values and monitor the `next` value to determine if another iteration is required.  Use `array_push()` with the spread operator to append new rows of data to your result array.

Code: ([Mock Demo](https://3v4l.org/GNJiM))

```
$url = "https://example.com/process/api/transactions/"
     . "from/$yesterday/to/$today/for/company/$company?offset=%d&limit=%d"; 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");                                                                                                                                    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: $cookie"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);                                                                                                                                            

$offset = 0;
$limit = 1000;
$result = [];
do {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, sprintf($url, $offset, $limit));
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    // save the returned json string to your system if you wish
    $response = json_decode($json, true);
    array_push($result, ...$response['results']);
    $offset += $limit;
} while (!empty($response['next']));
var_export($result);
```